# Database design: status of one table based on another

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, stored-procedures, triggers

I have an odd business requirement that has me stumped. Some background: basically, I have two tables for tracking program enhancements: Enhancement and Bug. The relationship for Enhancement->Bug is 1:m, and the Bug table has a foreign key column EnhancementID.

Both tables have a "Status" column, but this is where it gets tricky. My requirement is that the status of an Enhancement is dependent on its related Bugs. For example, if we have 3 Bugs with EnhancementID's of 100 and Statuses of "In Testing", then Enhancement 100's status should automatically be set to "In Testing." There are several status rules like this.

This database is shared by a few applications, so my first thought was to use an "On Update" trigger on the Bug table. Because the trigger had a Select statement in the triggering table, I received a "mutating table" error (I have to query the statuses of all bugs with the specified EnhancementID when the trigger fires). Now, I am trying to implement a three trigger solution as outlined here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936 but I am becoming wary of putting so much logic within database triggers.

So my question is: am I approaching this problem reasonably? Is there a better way someone could suggest? Perhaps using a view for the Enhancement's status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a view.

There is no simple way to synchronize data accross rows/tables. As you've found triggers lead to mutating errors and are a source of uncountable bugs. If you want to avoid mutating errors, look at this [workaround by Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936) (this will probably help you understand why triggers are not the best tool in this case).

You could use application procedures or PL/SQL API but note that they will only work if you use them all the time (which means that you never ever issue a single direct update to these tables). A single developer that forgets to use the API will desynchronize your data. Personally I would only consider an API if the status is so complex to compute on the fly that the view is not acceptable performance-wise.

Since this is **redundant information** (the status of the enhancement can be deducted entirely from the status of its bugs), you don't need to store it in a database column.

If you can express your rule in a SQL query, this is straightforward, for instance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW enhancement_with_status_v AS
SELECT e.*,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DECODE(b.status, 'T', 1)) >= 1 THEN 'T'
            WHEN ...
            ELSE ...
       END status
  FROM enhancement e,
  LEFT JOIN bugs b ON b.enhancement_id = e.enhancement_id
 GROUP BY e...
```

If the rules are too complex, you can write a PL/SQL function and call this function from SQL.

The view also has the advantage that when the rules change (as most rules do), you will not need to update your whole table.

Comment: I was actually building my triggers per the suggestions in that workaround by Tom Kyte. Another problem I have is that I can't really change the applications to use a different table from the current Enhancement table. Would it be possible to update the status of the Enhancement table based on this view?

Comment: So you're trying to work around an application with triggers, that must be... unpleasant! You could rename your table and call the view "enhancement", but that will probably raise more problems that it solves. Truly if you have no control over the application the unintended consequences will be hard to predict.

Comment: In agree with @VincentMalgrat -- use a view if you can.  A trigger-based approach is not going to work correctly unless you have have some form of locking (which the suggested trigger-based workaround does not) -- the fundamental problem being that the trigger cannot "see" changes made by other transactions (like adding or updating another bug with a status of "In Testing").

Comment: @BrianCamire -- why can't the trigger(s) "see" changes by other transactions? Shouldn't they fire every time there is an update to a Bug status? I like the idea of using a view, but I'm trying to wrap my head around how this would change things. I'm not sure what the implications of changing the Enhancement table to be a view are, from the apps' perspectives.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat -- Yes, you have no idea....I'm trying to use triggers because different apps update the status of a Bug...so something needs to automagically update the status of an Enhancement.

Comment: @user2811300, they can't see changes made by other *concurrent* transactions *that haven't been committed yet*.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to [this](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10770782) might work.

Try to have one after update trigger to check the distinct status per enhancement and update the same status in enhancement.

Comment: I think this is similar to what I tried in my first attempt, where I received a "mutating table" error for using a SELECT in the trigger.

Comment: If you try to update table b after update on table a, why should you face a mutating table error?

Comment: Because I have to query table a in the trigger to determine the status update on table b. This causes the mutating table error.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions for this.

1. Database triggers as mentioned in the question
2. Use your application to update the parent status (status of the enhancement) manually. Do not forget to index the foreign key in the child table else deadlock is quite inevitable in distributed application systems

Comment: Thanks, but using the application isn't really an option here: the database is shared amongst a few applications.